# jquery show/hide on each category

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am just trying to product list sidebar by product category. i want when i click a category, its show only this category product and another hide.

**my jquery code**

```
  


    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".show_hide").show();
       $(".slidingDiv").hide();

       $('.show_hide').click(function () {
       $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
     });
   });
```

**my php code**

```
<? foreach($test as $t): ?>
            <big><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='show_hide'><?php $t['category']; ?></a></big>
        <?
        $cat_id=$t['category_id'];
            $query1=$this->db->query("select * from product where category_id='$cat_id'");
            $test1=$query1->result_array();
        ?>
        <div class='slidingDiv'>
                <? foreach($test1 as $t1):?>
                    <a href='<?php print base_url('index.php/admin_panel/product/'.$t1['product_id'])?>'><?php print $t1['product_name']; ?></a><br/>
                <?php   endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        <?php   endforeach; ?>
```

My problem is when i click a category every categoy shown all product.

**How can I show each category's products  inside *foreach* loop?**

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: Also... the PHP code is buggy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".show_hide").show();
   $(".slidingDiv").hide();

   $('.show_hide').click(function () {
      $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
   });
});
```

In this case you are only calling the `slideToggle` on one element. In your case you are calling it an all the elements with the `slidingDiv` class.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could give a look to jQuery UI, in specific the accordion:

[jQueryUI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".show_hide").on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: I think it will work in your current code. Did it solved your query?

Comment: I have already provided the `click` event you just need to apply it and see. @emon